# angularjs 1 ngModel two $watchs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [angular google places directive plugin](https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete/tree/0.2.7). when user selects the address then it shows on `$scope.watch`, but I want to watch every key hit, so I can clear other values, if user start changing any value on the input box.

Is there a way to watch for any key or value changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue in your case is that the Google Places directive does not update the variable assigned to `ng-model` ($scope.place) until a selection is made from the dropdown menu. This makes sense - the point is for the user to decide which place is the one they are looking for, out of several results.

Check out the source to see where this happens:
https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete/blob/0.2.7/src/autocomplete.js#L70

https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete/blob/0.2.7/src/autocomplete.js#L166

I'm including a code snippet of the plugin in case it will help anyone else with future debugging. You'll need to add your Maps API key to make it work.

```js
"use strict";

angular.module('example', ['google.places'])

// Setup a basic controller with a scope variable 'place'
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.place = null;
  $scope.updatePlace = function() {
    console.log($scope.place);
  };
});


angular.module("google.places",[]).factory("googlePlacesApi",["$window",function(a){if(!a.google)throw"Global `google` var missing. Did you forget to include the places API script?";return a.google}]).directive("gPlacesAutocomplete",["$parse","$compile","$timeout","$document","googlePlacesApi",function(a,b,c,d,e){return{restrict:"A",require:"^ngModel",scope:{model:"=ngModel",options:"=?",forceSelection:"=?",customPlaces:"=?"},controller:["$scope",function(a){}],link:function(a,f,g,h){function i(){f.bind("keydown",l),f.bind("blur",m),f.bind("submit",m),a.$watch("selected",n)}function j(){var c,e=angular.element("<div g-places-autocomplete-drawer></div>"),f=angular.element(d[0].body);e.attr({input:"input",query:"query",predictions:"predictions",active:"active",selected:"selected"}),c=b(e)(a),f.append(c)}function k(){h.$parsers.push(o),h.$formatters.push(p),h.$render=q}function l(b){0!==a.predictions.length&&-1!==w(A,b.which)&&(b.preventDefault(),b.which===z.down?(a.active=(a.active+1)%a.predictions.length,a.$digest()):b.which===z.up?(a.active=(a.active?a.active:a.predictions.length)-1,a.$digest()):13===b.which||9===b.which?(a.forceSelection&&(a.active=-1===a.active?0:a.active),a.$apply(function(){a.selected=a.active,-1===a.selected&&r()})):27===b.which&&a.$apply(function(){b.stopPropagation(),r()}))}function m(b){0!==a.predictions.length&&(a.forceSelection&&(a.selected=-1===a.selected?0:a.selected),a.$digest(),a.$apply(function(){-1===a.selected&&r()}))}function n(){var b;b=a.predictions[a.selected],b&&(b.is_custom?a.$apply(function(){a.model=b.place,a.$emit("g-places-autocomplete:select",b.place),c(function(){h.$viewChangeListeners.forEach(function(a){a()})})}):C.getDetails({placeId:b.place_id},function(b,d){d==e.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK&&a.$apply(function(){a.model=b,a.$emit("g-places-autocomplete:select",b),c(function(){h.$viewChangeListeners.forEach(function(a){a()})})})}),r())}function o(b){var c;return b&&u(b)?(a.query=b,c=angular.extend({input:b},a.options),B.getPlacePredictions(c,function(b,c){a.$apply(function(){var d;r(),a.customPlaces&&(d=s(a.query),a.predictions.push.apply(a.predictions,d)),c==e.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK&&a.predictions.push.apply(a.predictions,b),a.predictions.length>5&&(a.predictions.length=5)})}),a.forceSelection?h.$modelValue:b):b}function p(a){var b="";return u(a)?b=a:v(a)&&(b=a.formatted_address),b}function q(){return f.val(h.$viewValue)}function r(){a.active=-1,a.selected=-1,a.predictions=[]}function s(b){var c,d,e,f=[];for(e=0;e<a.customPlaces.length;e++)c=a.customPlaces[e],d=t(b,c),d.matched_substrings.length>0&&f.push({is_custom:!0,custom_prediction_label:c.custom_prediction_label||"(Custom Non-Google Result)",description:c.formatted_address,place:c,matched_substrings:d.matched_substrings,terms:d.terms});return f}function t(a,b){var c,d,e,f=a+"",g=[],h=[];for(d=b.formatted_address.split(","),e=0;e<d.length;e++)c=d[e].trim(),f.length>0&&(c.length>=f.length?(x(c,f)&&h.push({length:f.length,offset:e}),f=""):x(f,c)?(h.push({length:c.length,offset:e}),f=f.replace(c,"").trim()):f=""),g.push({value:c,offset:b.formatted_address.indexOf(c)});return{matched_substrings:h,terms:g}}function u(a){return"[object String]"==Object.prototype.toString.call(a)}function v(a){return"[object Object]"==Object.prototype.toString.call(a)}function w(a,b){var c,d;if(null==a)return-1;for(d=a.length,c=0;d>c;c++)if(a[c]===b)return c;return-1}function x(a,b){return 0===y(a).lastIndexOf(y(b),0)}function y(a){return null==a?"":a.toLowerCase()}var z={tab:9,enter:13,esc:27,up:38,down:40},A=[z.tab,z.enter,z.esc,z.up,z.down],B=new e.maps.places.AutocompleteService,C=new e.maps.places.PlacesService(f[0]);!function(){a.query="",a.predictions=[],a.input=f,a.options=a.options||{},j(),i(),k()}()}}}]).directive("gPlacesAutocompleteDrawer",["$window","$document",function(a,b){var c=['<div class="pac-container" ng-if="isOpen()" ng-style="{top: position.top+\'px\', left: position.left+\'px\', width: position.width+\'px\'}" style="display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">','  <div class="pac-item" g-places-autocomplete-prediction index="$index" prediction="prediction" query="query"','       ng-repeat="prediction in predictions track by $index" ng-class="{\'pac-item-selected\': isActive($index) }"','       ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectPrediction($index)" role="option" id="{{prediction.id}}">',"  </div>","</div>"];return{restrict:"A",scope:{input:"=",query:"=",predictions:"=",active:"=",selected:"="},template:c.join(""),link:function(c,d){function e(c){var d=c[0],e=d.getBoundingClientRect(),f=b[0].documentElement,g=b[0].body,h=a.pageYOffset||f.scrollTop||g.scrollTop,i=a.pageXOffset||f.scrollLeft||g.scrollLeft;return{width:e.width,height:e.height,top:e.top+e.height+h,left:e.left+i}}d.bind("mousedown",function(a){a.preventDefault()}),a.onresize=function(){c.$apply(function(){c.position=e(c.input)})},c.isOpen=function(){return c.predictions.length>0},c.isActive=function(a){return c.active===a},c.selectActive=function(a){c.active=a},c.selectPrediction=function(a){c.selected=a},c.$watch("predictions",function(){c.position=e(c.input)},!0)}}}]).directive("gPlacesAutocompletePrediction",[function(){var a=['<span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span>','<span class="pac-item-query" ng-bind-html="prediction | highlightMatched"></span>','<span ng-repeat="term in prediction.terms | unmatchedTermsOnly:prediction">{{term.value | trailingComma:!$last}}&nbsp;</span>','<span class="custom-prediction-label" ng-if="prediction.is_custom">&nbsp;{{prediction.custom_prediction_label}}</span>'];return{restrict:"A",scope:{index:"=",prediction:"=",query:"="},template:a.join("")}}]).filter("highlightMatched",["$sce",function(a){return function(b){var c,d="",e="";return b.matched_substrings.length>0&&b.terms.length>0&&(c=b.matched_substrings[0],d=b.terms[0].value.substr(c.offset,c.length),e=b.terms[0].value.substr(c.offset+c.length)),a.trustAsHtml('<span class="pac-matched">'+d+"</span>"+e)}}]).filter("unmatchedTermsOnly",[function(){return function(a,b){var c,d,e=[];for(c=0;c<a.length;c++)d=a[c],b.matched_substrings.length>0&&d.offset>b.matched_substrings[0].length&&e.push(d);return e}}]).filter("trailingComma",[function(){return function(a,b){return b?a+",":a}}]);
```

```css
.pac-container{background-color:#fff;position:absolute!important;z-index:1000;border-radius:2px;border-top:1px solid #d9d9d9;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;overflow:hidden}.pac-container:after{content:"";padding:1px 1px 1px 0;height:16px;text-align:right;display:block;background-image:url(//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white2.png);background-position:right;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:104px 16px}.hdpi.pac-container:after{background-image:url(//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white2_hdpi.png)}.pac-item{cursor:default;padding:0 4px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;line-height:30px;text-align:left;border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;font-size:11px;color:#999}.pac-item:hover{background-color:#fafafa}.pac-item-selected,.pac-item-selected:hover{background-color:#ebf2fe}.pac-matched{font-weight:700}.pac-item-query{font-size:13px;padding-right:3px;color:#000}.pac-icon{width:15px;height:20px;margin-right:7px;margin-top:6px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;background-image:url(//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons.png);background-size:34px}.hdpi .pac-icon{background-image:url(//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons_hdpi.png)}.pac-icon-search{background-position:-1px -1px}.pac-item-selected .pac-icon-search{background-position:-18px -1px}.pac-icon-marker{background-position:-1px -161px}.pac-item-selected .pac-icon-marker{background-position:-18px -161px}.pac-placeholder{color:gray}.custom-prediction-label{font-style:italic}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Required dependencies -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=INSERT_YOUR_GMAPS_API_HERE&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="example" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Basic Usage</h1>

            <h5>Result:</h5>
            <pre>{{place | json}}</pre>
          
            <form class="form">
                <input class="form-control" g-places-autocomplete ng-model="place" ng-change="updatePlace()"/>
            </form>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```